# SPI and video streaming using Wifi

Tags: streaming-video

We are developing a shield that shall be interfaced to the pi. A camera(720p) is also interfaced to the pi via the USB on the pi . The data from the camera is to be converted into H.264 format and then via a wifi module(in the shield) transmitted.

Kindly help me out in the following points -

1) Is H.264 available in the pi ? I do not want to use a chip that will encode my video. If yes, then how can i tap the h.264 encoded signals ? Is it through the SPI on the 26 pin connector ? Or can it be tapped from the other USB in the USB hub (there I 2 USB slots,I believe).

2) If H.264 is obtained via SPI (thru the 26 pin conn), will the speed of the SPI be enough to prevent any latencies as I intend to stream the video using a wifi module. The USB speed is 480Mbps. Is the USB not better than SPI here ?

3) The H.264 is a compression tool. My video is 1280x720x25(fps)x8(8 bit colour)x3 = 552960000bits/sec ~ 66MB (bytes). H.264 will compress it by a factor. What is that factor ? How can I select that factor(if such an option is available). How can I do that in the pi ?

4) Will the selection of any of the wifi modules suffice ? I am going for b/g modules(max of 54Mb/sec)

Regards,
Vin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was many questions... I have the feeling a fast search could be more effective. Anyway, here are some thoughts.

1) [This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/what-speed-can-i-expect-from-the-hardware-h264-encoding) indicates that the GPU supports H.264 encoding, but that its not clear if there is software to use the GPU for encoding.

2) That is a very high bit rate, more than the 480 Mbit/s of USB. You cannot expect to get even 480 Mbit/s of useful data over USB due to various overheads. [This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/699/what-spi-frequencies-does-raspberry-pi-support) indicates that the SPI can run at 125 MHz, which gives you roughly 15 Mbytes/s. (250 Mbit/s is discussed but looks uncertain)
Some USB webcams do JPEG compression of each frame before sending it over USB. This will depend on your camera module - do you have a camera module that actually outputs such a lot of data, and do you really want it?

3) The compression factor is something you are typically free to choose as you wish, it is a trade-off between high compression and high quality. You would set this factor as an option in the encoder program, the details depend on the encoder.

4) Get a Wifi module with good linux support! See [linuxwireless.org](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/). Most adapters work for basic things as participating in a wireless network. For more special applications, such as providing an [access point](http://itsacleanmachine.blogspot.com/2013/02/wifi-access-point-with-raspberry-pi.html), you have to choose more carefully.

Finally, the Foundation is developing a [camera module](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1254) that attaches to the CSI connector. It seems not to be available yet, but [soon](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/3224). They promise H.624 encoding of the video, so maybe this is exactly what you want.